# Understanding Gridview RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've coded a gridview that doesn't fire when I click the edit button and I found an older question that addresses my issue by just using e.CommandName with if statements under the RowCommand method.  I'm trying to figure out how to implement it with my code.

My question is, how do I use e.RowIndex during update to find my controls and reference those now? Also, I've tried calling my old Update method but it won't let me use sender and e as parameters because GridviewCommandEventArgs is different from GridViewEventUpdateArgs.    I'm pretty lost, any help would be appreciated in straightening this out.

C#:

```
void RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{  
    // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {

    }
   if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
        UpdateCustomer(sender, e);
        string nFirstName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFirstName")).Text;
        string nLastName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtLastName")).Text;
        string nEmergency = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmergency")).Text;
        string nCell = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCell")).Text;
        string nAge = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtAge")).Text;
        string nActivityCard = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtActivityCard")).Text;
        string nBoat = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBoat")).Text;
        string nInitials = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtInitials")).Text;
        string nGroup = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtGroup")).Text;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "update Person set FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName, " +
         "Emergency#=@Emergency, Cell#=@Cell, Age=@Age, ActivityCard=@ActivityCard, Initials=@Initials, CraftType=@Boat, Group#=@Group " +
         "where Person.PersonID=@Pid;" +
         "SELECT Person.PersonID, Person.FirstName AS FirstName, Person.LastName AS LastName, Person.Emergency# AS Emergency#, Person.Cell# AS Cell#, Person.Age AS Age, " +
        "Person.ActivityCard AS ActivityCard, Person.CraftType AS CraftType, Person.Initials AS Initials, Person.Group# AS Group# " +
        "FROM Person INNER JOIN " +
        "TripSchedule ON Person.PersonID = TripSchedule.PersonID where TripSchedule.Date = @Date and " +
        "TripSchedule.Time = @Time and TripSchedule.TripType = @Type order by Person.Group#;";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nFirstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nLastName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emergency", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nEmergency;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cell", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nCell;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nAge;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActivityCard", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nActivityCard;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Initials", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nInitials;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Boat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nBoat;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Group", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nGroup;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", ddlTripTime.SelectedItem.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", ddlTripType.SelectedItem.ToString());
        long personID = long.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["PersonID"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pid", personID);
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "Cancel")
    {

    }

}
```

ASP.NET:

```
<div id="dvGrid" style="padding: 0px">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="PersonID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="blue" HeaderStyle-BackColor="aqua"
                        ShowFooter="true" OnRowEditing="EditCustomer" OnRowUpdating="UpdateCustomer"
                        OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Height="95px">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server"  Height="20px" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width = "60px" />
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" width="60px"  MaxLength="15" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Last Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("LastName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" width="60px" MaxLength="15" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Age">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" Width="30px" MaxLength="2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Activity Card">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblActivityCard" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ActivityCard")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtActivityCard" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ActivityCard")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtActivityCard" Width="50px" MaxLength="7" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Cell Phone">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCell" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cell#")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCell" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cell#")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCell" Width="70px" MaxLength="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Emergency Phone">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmergency" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Emergency#")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmergency" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Emergency#")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmergency" width="70px" MaxLength="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>               
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Boat Type">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblBoat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CraftType")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CraftType")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoat" Width="80px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Initials">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblInitials" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Initials")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInitials" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Initials")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInitials" width="30px" MaxLength="2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Group #">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblGroup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group#")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGroup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group#")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGroup" MaxLength="2" Width="20px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PersonID")%>'
                                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" Text="Delete"
                                        OnClick="DeleteCustomer"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="AddNewCustomer" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
    </EditItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>

                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Are you using a `<asp:LinkButton..` or something for your command? Can you post the code for the gridview template definition?

Comment: @DennisR I have them set as LinkButtons, yes.  I posted the ASP.NET code for the gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `RowIndex` as CommandArgument for your LinkButtons.

```
 <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>Update</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Which can be access from code behind. Using `rowindex` you can get hold of the current row and find any controls using `FindControl`

```
void RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{ 
    int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
      ....
    }

    if (e.CommandName == "Cancel")
    {
      ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This isn't the first time you've helped me..I'm working on my first application by myself.  Would you consider helping me out and being a mentor for me?  Maybe just allowing me to email you with questions I have and such as I encounter problems?  I understand if you don't want to take on that sort of responsibility. Thank you for any consideration.

Comment: @user3267755 Glad to help :) I didn't realize until now that I have answered some of your questions (because your member id didn't register in my mind). It's been years now since I coded for webforms as I'm more into Asp.Net MVC. I know there are lot of experts out there on SO who will surely help you on your questions with their different ideas instead of just me guiding you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration and kind words. :)

Comment: @user3267755 I've my email out there in my profile. You can email your questions and I'll try my best as time permits.

Answer (score 0):

`e.CommandArgument` will contain the index of the row clicked, so you can access the relevant controls via

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
GridView1.Rows[index].Controls[x];
```